# How can I refresh an OAuth2 token? Do I need to wait for the token to Expire? (Patreon API)

Tags: rest, typescript, express, oauth-2.0, patreon

I'm trying out OAuth using Patreon's api. I've very new to the OAuth process and had been using Patreon's Javascript Package to help manage the request for me.

- NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/patreon
- Patreon Documentation: https://docs.patreon.com/#introduction

So far I've been able to successfully get the token via:

```
import * as patreon from 'patreon';
const patreonOAuthClient = patreon.oauth(clientId, clientSecret);
patreonOAuthClient.getTokens(oauthGrantCode, redirectURL).then((tokenResponse) => { 
     console.log(tokenResponse);
})
```

The token I recieve comes out like this:

```
   // Example Token from getTokens()'s then()-response
   tokenResponse = {
        access_token: "UbHYT3H51GpeYueBeBuvBj1fnEFzv5A5870s_rYeMHo",
        expires_in: 2678400,
        refresh_token: "AP5aAw-gJbVf35tWxQb74rmJJz2MhwIYq660m0jiZQ4",
        scope: "my-campaign pledges-to-me users",
        token_type: "Bearer",
        version: "0.0.1"
    }
```

In my local server, I'm trying to get refresh token to work so I don't have to keep asking users permission every month.

Although when I use the refresh token method I get a 400 Bad Request:

```
patreonOAuthClient.refreshToken(tokenResponse).then(response => {
      console.log(response, 'success!');
}).catch(err => {
      console.log(err, ':(');
});
```

It's not shown in the npm documentation but you can find **refreshToken()** on the [github source code](https://github.com/Patreon/patreon-js/blob/master/src/oauth.js) of patreon.

According to [here](https://docs.patreon.com/#step-7-keeping-up-to-date) in their api documents:

> If you wish to get up-to-date information after the token has expired,
>   a new token may be issued to be used for the following month. To
>   refresh a token, make a POST request to the token endpoint with a
>   grant type of refresh_token, as in the example. You may also manually
>   refresh the token on the appropriate client in your clients page.

So is the reason I'm getting 400 because I need to wait a month to refresh the token or am I just incorrectly implementing the API? I'm hoping someone with more OAuth experience can tell me if we should be doing token refreshes either **before** or **after** the token expires?

(If you refresh it before it expires is there a certain way to time an express server to do it before the month expires? As I think it adding a timeout for each token would be really bad for memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the SDK working.. I was under the impression from the source code that the token was the object received from the response. But it turns out that the token is the string value.

So:

```
// Using tokenResponse.refresh_token instead of just tokenResponse
patreonOAuthClient.refreshToken(tokenResponse.refresh_token).then(response => {
      console.log(response, 'success!');
}).catch(err => {
      console.log(err, ':(');
});
```